# Google+ quick-start sample app crashes

Tags: android, google-plus

I'm following [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/android#install-sdk) & trying to get the [sample code](https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-android) "gplus-quickstart-android" working. I get the project built without errors. However, when I try to run the app on my device (connected with usb to my laptop), the app crashes immediately.
I see this error `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.google.android.gms.plus.sample.quickstart.MainActivity`

This is the logging:

```
07-21 10:49:10.699: E/Trace(22334): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
07-21 10:49:10.779: W/dalvikvm(22334): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4100e450)
07-21 10:49:10.809: E/AndroidRuntime(22334): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-21 10:49:10.809: E/AndroidRuntime(22334): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gms.plus.sample.quickstart/com.google.android.gms.plus.sample.quickstart.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.plus.sample.quickstart.MainActivity
07-21 10:49:10.809: E/AndroidRuntime(22334):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1991)
07-21 10:49:10.809: E/AndroidRuntime(22334):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092)
07-21 10:49:10.809: E/AndroidRuntime(22334):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:133)
07-21 10:49:10.809: E/AndroidRuntime(22334):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1203)
07-21 10:49:10.809: E/AndroidRuntime(22334):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-21 10:49:10.809: E/AndroidRuntime(22334):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-21 10:49:10.809: E/AndroidRuntime(22334):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4794)
07-21 10:49:10.809: E/AndroidRuntime(22334):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-21 10:49:10.809: E/AndroidRuntime(22334):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-21 10:49:10.809: E/AndroidRuntime(22334):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
07-21 10:49:10.809: E/AndroidRuntime(22334):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
07-21 10:49:10.809: E/AndroidRuntime(22334):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-21 10:49:10.809: E/AndroidRuntime(22334): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.plus.sample.quickstart.MainActivity
07-21 10:49:10.809: E/AndroidRuntime(22334):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
07-21 10:49:10.809: E/AndroidRuntime(22334):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
07-21 10:49:10.809: E/AndroidRuntime(22334):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
07-21 10:49:10.809: E/AndroidRuntime(22334):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
07-21 10:49:10.809: E/AndroidRuntime(22334):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1982)
07-21 10:49:10.809: E/AndroidRuntime(22334):    ... 11 more
```

Does anybody have a hint how to solve this or what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Where is your MainActivity class, can you show it.

Comment: Show us your proper source codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After importing the project `MainActivity.java` was not in src folder, it was in java folder.

So, I made `MainActivity.java` in src folder with package name `com.google.android.gms.plus.sample.quickstart` & copied the code in `MainActivity.java`

`MainActivity` uses `FragmentActivity` so, I added `android-support-v4.jar` into my project.

Then run the project !

Comment: This solution works but the actual root cause is that this sample project is setup as an Android Studio project instead of an eclipse project.